# last parameter array on json_decode

Tags: php, json

Hello guys i have this string JSON and I decode it with function php `json_decode($var,true)`

```
[{"id":"4","name":"Elis"},{"id":"5","name":"Eilbert"}]
```

Like result i receive this array

```
Array( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Elis ) 
       [1] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => Eilbert ))1
```

What is it the last number "1" on the end of the array? why is there? I don't want have it how can i delete it?

On js i pass an array converted with JSON.stringify() and the result is like the first json code.

```
$user = json_decode($this->input->post('to'),true);
                $conv_user_id = array();
                foreach ($user as $po) {
                    $conv_user_id[] = $po['id'];
                    $conv_user_id[] = $id_user;

                }

                echo print_r($user);
```

@explosion phill pointed out to me that my json string is wrapped with `[]` i pass just an array in js converted it witj JSON.stringify(), wich is the error?

Comment: Do you mean `json_decode`?

Comment: Show your actual code, please

Comment: That is not valid JSON either.  Is it wrapped in `[]`?

Comment: Which method did you show ?

Comment: Now that i checked out better yes Explosion have center the point. is wrapped with [] how can i delete it?

Comment: what are you trying to delete

Comment: i don't want have the wrap [] on my json string

Comment: you have this echo print_r($user); it will print []

Answer (score 4):

You're misusing [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r):

```
echo print_r($user);
```

> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.
>
> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the **return value is TRUE**.

... and when you cast boolean `TRUE` to string you get `1`.

Comment: Exactly, i didn't know, but i is not this one the mine problem but you have answer correctly to my question.

Answer (score 1):

[Learn more about](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) json_decode — Decodes a JSON string.

Example Common mistakes using json_decode()

```
<?php

// the following strings are valid JavaScript but not valid JSON

// the name and value must be enclosed in double quotes
// single quotes are not valid 
$bad_json = "{ 'bar': 'baz' }";
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// the name must be enclosed in double quotes
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// trailing commas are not allowed
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz", }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

?>
```

[Ref:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)